# Cordova clicking on input scales site, how to avoid that

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest

The problem is that when you click on an input, the HTML page suddenly gets wider. It however does not revert back to it's old position when the input is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the times it automatically sets the windowSoftInputMode (when the keyboard popups) to `adjustResize`.
You can fix this by adding this to the activity tag in the android manifest.xml:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`